# Content-Disposition file extension not properly working on Firefox

Tags: java, spring-mvc, csv, browser, content-disposition

I have the following code on Spring Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public void downloadActive(@RequestParam(value = "type") String offerType, HttpServletResponse response,
            HttpSession session) throws Exception {

 StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();.
.
.

response.addHeader("Content-Disposition: ", "attachment; filename=my" + offerType + "Offers.csv");
response.getWriter().write(b.toString());
..

}
```

This code get executed when a download button from EXt Js is clicked. On chrome, it directly downloads the file as a *.csv format and when the user opens it, it will use Excel automatically to open the file, if they already have installed and this is the right behavior I wanted to have.

However, on firefox, it prompts a save as window with open with and save options. If I use open with option, it tells me the filename is filename.csv but the type is chrome htm file. I haven't mentioned htm anywhere in my code and I dont know why its trying  to open it as htm instead of csv file. Once it tries to open it, it brings excel application and the contents are in a bad format.

Is there a way to avoid this problem on firefox ?

Thanks

Comment: Get an HTTP trace and show us all of the response header fields.

Comment: I ran into this problem earlier tonight and none of the other suggestions in this thread worked. In my case it was an XLSX file to be downloaded. All browsers except Firefox seem to work just fine. I am also using Spring MVC as you appear to be. I augmented the `produces` annotation to include the Excel MIME type and it is now fixing the issue in Firefox.

In my case this meant a controller annotation of: `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding double quotes (`"`) for the file name fixes the problem.

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "");
```

Comment: I was running into this problem earlier tonight and tried applying the double-quote fix as you suggested, although it didn't make any difference. Do note also that the quotes after fileName would actually be `"\""`, not `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if I am not sure why it worked, changing the addHeader Method to setHeader fixed the issue.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition: ", "attachment; filename=my" + offerType + "Offers.csv");
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the trailing ": " in the header name parameter is incorrect. Also, you want to set Content-Type.

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintWriter printWriter = resourceResponse.getWriter();
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
resourceResponse.setContentType("text/csv");
resourceResponse.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL,
        "max-age=0, must-revalidate");
resourceResponse.setProperty(
        HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
        "attachment; filename=" + "export_build" + "_"
                + date.getTime() + ".csv");
printWriter.write(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Make sure to write the content after printing the header to ensure content is packaged in a file properly.